# Can I use a pair of 2x48GB RAM kits instead of a 4x48GB kit?

Tags: memory, bios, motherboard, hardware-failure, xmp

I am planning to build a PC for deep learning using 192GB of RAM. The only available 192GB RAM kit option by now is from Corsair that runs at 5200MHz speed. But there are better options in 2x48GB kits running even at 7000MHz.

I am wondering can I buy a pair of the same 2x48GB RAM kits and hope to reach faster speed in the future based on newer BIOS or Firmware updates? Or this is a hardware issue that is not resolvable through future software updates?

PS: I know people struggling even on running 4x32GB RAMs and it's not stable today, but I would like to buy something future prove that maybe would work after some software updated?

I am also aware there is a similar question available but as long as that question is from 7 years ago, I thought maybe something has changed during the last years or there are some new experiences from other people about this?

Comment: What do you want to use the computer for?

Comment: Hardware buying recommendations are [offtopic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here, sorry. [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is a question and answer site for people seeking specific hardware recommendations.

Comment: @Gantendo Deep learning

Comment: @Gantendo I do not seek any specific brands. I just wanted to know why some people say it's not good to buy two kits of 2x RAMs instead of one kit of 4x RAM?

Comment: I think its basically because of https://superuser.com/questions/1110030/is-it-risky-to-purchase-two-kits-of-64gb-ram-instead-of-single-kit-of-128gb-ram/1110043#1110043 only its probably a mix of actual fact and superstition but i don't know the percentages

Comment: @Gantendo Yes but it's for 7 years ago and I thought maybe something has changed or there are new  experiences to know?

Comment: afaik nothing has changed in this department but i am not sane enough to trust in these matters

Comment: BIOS or firmware updates may fix problems with system stability but they are highly unlikely to lead to significant performance gains without hardware replacement.

Comment: 48GB module is a 48GB module, it being a set, is essentially only for warranty purposes